# Call a public method of a class, from a public method of another class

Tags: javascript, class, oop, methods

How can I call **methodOne** from **methodTwo**?

Is there a safe and correct way?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var classOne = new ClassOne();
    var classTwo = new ClassTwo();
});

var ClassOne = (function (window, document, Math, undefined) {

    function ClassOne () {
    }

    ClassOne.prototype = {
        methodOne: function () {
            console.log('method one');
        }
    };

    return ClassOne;
})(window, document, Math, undefined);

var ClassTwo = (function (window, document, Math, undefined) {

    function ClassTwo () {
    }

    ClassTwo.prototype = {
        methodTwo: function () {
            // how to call?
            // classOne.methodOne()
        }
    };

    return ClassTwo;
})(window, document, Math, undefined);
```

Comment: You forgot the `return` your constructors from the IEFEs, and you are using them before defining them.

Comment: Those methods are *instance methods*. How does the `classTwo` instance know of the `classOne` instance to call the method on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I call methodOne from methodTwo?

You need to access the instance on which you want to call the method (you could as well get it from the prototype and apply on some arbitrary object but I guess that's not what you want). To make it known in the scope of the `methodTwo`, pass it as a parameter to the function:

```
ClassTwo.prototype.methodTwo = function (one) {
    one.methodOne();
};

…

var classOne = new ClassOne();
var classTwo = new ClassTwo();
classTwo.methodTwo(classOne);
```

Comment: Alternatively, he can create the instance inside `methodTwo`.